# Defining business objects in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Trying to understand Entity Framework. My approach is database first. However I would like to define other entites in the model that is closer to my business objects. I guess I could write queries in the db and include them in the model. But I would also like to define entirely new entities in the model though they would be based on underlying tables in the db. How do I do that - does anyone know a tutorial?

Regards
Bjørn
db Oldtimer, EF Newbie

Answer (score 0):

Database first means that you have existing database and you can either create model by updating from database or manually. You can use wizard to create initial model and modify it manually to define new entities but you must not use update from database any more or some of your changes will be deleted. Also your custom modifications must follow EF mapping rules (for example it is not directly possible to map multiple entities to the same table except some more advanced mapping scenarios like splitting and inheritance) and some of them (custom queries) must be done directly in EDMX source (XML) because designer doesn't support them - this requires more complex knowledge of EF mapping and it will be definitely hard for newbie.

You can check [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399604.aspx) of that XML. For entities mapped to custom queries you will have to use [DefiningQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738450.aspx) element in SSDL part of EDMX.